# How to store my own variables on flask

Tags: python, flask

I need to define my own variables that would be saved on server while it's running. I am trying to use `flask.g` but it throws an error:

```
AttributeError: '_AppCtxGlobals' object has no attribute 'x'
```

Here is the code:

```
from flask import *
app=Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def opa():
    #Added this to define variable
    try:
        g.x
    except NameError:
        g.x=None
    #Added this to add value to variable
    if g.x is None:
        g.x='Already defined'
        return 'x is now defined'
    else:
        return g.x
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8081,debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler way would be to do it like the following :

```
x = getattr(flask.g, 'x', None)
if x is None:
    g.x = 'Already defined'
    return 'x is now defined'
else:
    return g.x
```

Alternatively, you can see that you code is throwing `AttributeError`. So if you want to keep your try/catch code, then you need to specifically catch `AttributeError` and not `TypeError`.

```
try:
    g.x
except AttributeError:
    g.x=None

if g.x is None:
    g.x='Already defined'
    return 'x is now defined'
else:
    return g.x
```

Comment: For the first part of code u wrote throws:
NameError: global name 'flask' is not defined

Comment: Second part works, but it doesn't save x on server. Every time i refresh the page it returns 'x is now defined'

Comment: @JaSamSale: `g` is reset for each and every request. If you need a *per application global*, don't use `g`, just set the global.

Comment: @MartijnPieters How do I set per app global?

Comment: @MartijnPieters found a way. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to do something different than your question intended. 'g' works per request. If you want to save something for the entire app, may be put it in `__init__.py` of the project.

Comment: @JaSamSale: Glad to have been of help!

Answer (score 3):

Accessing an attribute throws `AttributeError`, not `NameError`:

```
try:
    g.x
except AttributeError:
    g.x = None
```

You'd be better off using the [membership testing with `in`](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/#flask.g) here:

```
if 'x' not in g:
    g.x = 'Already defined'
    return 'x is now defined'
else:
    return g.x
```

The documentation I linked you to also offers using `g.get()` and `getattr()` as alternatives:

```
x = g.get('x', None)
# x = getattr(g, 'x', None)
if x is None:
    g.x = 'Already defined'
    return 'x is now defined'
else:
    return x
```

Do note that the `g` global context is still *tied to a request*; you cannot store globals on it that persist from request to request. `g` supports sharing data between different functions and templates of your app, not between requests.

Use actual globals for that (preferably set via the [`app.before_first_request()` hook](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/#flask.Flask.before_first_request), or use some form of caching (such as [Flask-Cache](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Cache/)).

Setting a application-wide global:

```
x = None

@app.before_first_request
def set_x():
    global x
    x = 'x is now defined'
```

By using `before_first_request` you ensure that `x` is set just once on application startup, even if you use a server that uses multiple processes to handle requests.

Or using caching:

```
from flask.ext.cache import Cache

cache = Cache(app)

@cache.memoize(timeout=3600)  # cache for one hour
def produce_x():
    return 'x is now defined'
```

then use `produce_x()` whenever you need `x` defined; this is helpful when calculating `x` is expensive, but must be recalculated from time to time.

Comment: It works but never returns x. I need it to save 'x="Already defined"' but it doesn't.